# GWT Super Dev Mode, how to enable Source Maps

Tags: google-chrome, gwt, mgwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

I´m running my MGWT Project with SuperDevMode on a code server.

For debugging they they said i should use Chrome and "enable source maps" in the Chrome Developer Settings. But in the Developer Settings i can only find "Enable JavaScript Source maps" and "Enable css Source maps". Both are enabled but i still can´t see *.java* files there.

I´m using Chrome Version 42.

How can i enable the Sourcemaps for debugging in Chrome?

**Solved: Switched from Chrome Canery to Chrome and used gwt 2.5.1 instead of 2.5.0!**

Comment: Enable JavaScript Source maps is the right one, it will map the javascript to whatever source it is generated from. The problem is somewhere else probably. What webserver are you using?

Comment: I´m starting the Codeserver from Eclipse on localhost:9876. In Chrome developer tools under sources, is localhost:9876 listed, but under this directory i can only find _.js_ files. Is it than a mapping error? or is it possibly a problem, because i´m using mgwt?

Comment: Did you try enabling SuperDevMode using the bookmarklets?

Comment: yes i have the bookmarks for enable on / off. It compiles fine, i can use my application. The problem is that i can´t debug.

Comment: Ok, and if you use CTRL+O to find source files, does it show java files?

Comment: No there are only _.js_ files. Here a screenshot of my console: ![Screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/OML7g35.png)

Comment: I have the same problem, anyone had a solution?

Answer (score 1):

open the console, click the settings button.

There you will find a checkbox "enable JavaScript Source Maps".
This box must be checked.

[image]